# Dropdownlist asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho uma produto que pode ser cadastrada em 2 lojas A e B se eu já fiz um cadastro no A como faço pro `Dropdownlist` me mostrar só mostrar opção B na próxima vez que for em cadastrar? como seria a lógica? usando Entityframework e Linq?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create(string businessId)
{
        var marketRest = new Rest
                             .MarketplaceRest(_appSettings.WebApiUrl, _appKeyBase64);

        var registerViewModel = new RegisterMarketPlaceViewModel
        {
            BusinessId = businessId,

        };
        registerViewModel.MarketNameSelectList = 
                registerViewModel.GetMarketplaceSelectList(marketRest, _memoryCache);

        return View(registerViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, vc tem um dropdown com dois itens A e B, se o produto A já foi cadastrado, vc quer mostrar que apenas o item B está disponível é isso ?

Comment: exatamente, só queria mostrar o B agora no caso, mas  não consegui pensar numa lógica até agora.

Comment: Como vc monta esse dropdown ? Pode mostrar seu código?

Comment: produto foi só exemplo, estou usando mongoDb não sei se você ja trabalhou com isso.

Comment: `.GetMarketplaceSelectList(marketRest, _memoryCache).Where(x => !x.Vendido)` não consegue identificar e filtrar antes de preencher ou dentro do método de busca, só retornar os disponíveis ?